# Historical snapshots of place's details

Tags: google-places-api

for my research project I am searching for historical information about restaurants, services etc. Google place API has a nice interface, but is there a possibility to request for any historical state of any place? I didn't find anything in the documentationhttps://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro , but maybe someone solves the same problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not currently available in Google Maps Platform -- **Places API**.

If you are interested to have this feature, you can file this as feature request in Google's Public Issue Tracker:
https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#issue_tracker

Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development.